# exponential parameter estimtion from the smallest k-th order statistics

Tags: maximum-likelihood, density-function, exponential-distribution, unbiased-estimator, order-statistics

Assume $X_1, X_2, X_3,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d. samples from Exp($\lambda$). Assume that the integer $k<n$, is it possible to find a an unbiased estimator for $\lambda$ from the k-th smallest ordered samples?
I know it is possible to derive the an expression for the distribution of the order statistics, but I need an estimator for the original distribution parameter.

Comment: By "k-th smallest ordered samples" would you mean all $k$ of the smallest values among the $X_i,$ the (single) $k^\text{th}$ order statistic, or something else?

Comment: yes from all samples that are smaller than $X_k$

Comment: That's not the same as any of the interpretations I proposed, so let's clarify: by "$X_k$" do you mean the $k^\text{th}$ smallest value and by "smaller than" do you mean "less than or equal to"?

Comment: Yes exactly. It is my bad, it should be "less than or equal to".
thanks

Comment: This observation scheme is called *Type II censoring* in lifetime analysis.

Comment: So I believe that this is nearly the same as [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/45001/10479).

Comment: Thanks Yves, it is an interesting answer!
though, from the simulations, I was expecting 2^0.5 to appear in the answer.
any idea how we obtained the the joint probability density?

Comment: The density is the product of the density for the observed values and of the Survival function for the censored values. Of related interest is the *Rényi's representation* for the order statistics of a sample from the exponential.